# Having trouble compiling c code with struct pass as param

Tags: c

I got two warning and error from the block of code below:

> test.c:12:26: warning: 'struct PrioirtyQueue' declared inside parameter list [enabled by default]
>       test.c:12:26: warning: its scope is only this definition or declaration, which is probably not what you want [enabled by default]
>       test.c: In function 'set_mask_bit':
>       test.c:13:3: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type

```
 struct PriorityQueue {

        unsigned queue_mask;
        int is_empty;
        int task_guid;

};

void set_mask_bit(struct PrioirtyQueue *q, unsigned x) {
    q->queue_mask = x; 
}

int main() {

    return 0;

}
```

Please show me what I need to fix.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`struct PrioirtyQueue` should be `struct PriorityQueue` (typo).

```
struct PrioirtyQueue;
           ||
struct PriorityQueue;
```

Comment: That was quick, thanks. I really need to get some sleep...

Answer (score 2):

You've misspelt `PriorityQueue` in:

```
void set_mask_bit(struct PrioirtyQueue *q, unsigned x) {
                             ^^
```